# Laravel 5.6.3 not working in Homestead 5.1.0 due to PHP nullable type declaration

Tags: laravel, vagrant, php-7, homestead

I use Virtual Box and Homestead for web development with Laravel. Multiple projects (Laravel 5.1-5.4) are working just fine, but today I updated Homestead and created a new Laravel project. Instead of a welcome screen, the browser just shows me a white page.

`laravel.log` mentions a syntax error:

`[2018-02-13 08:47:49] local.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) at /home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/symfony/routing/Route.php:53)`

There's indeed a question mark in said line. It's part of a nullable type declaration which was introduced in PHP 7.1.:

`public function __construct(string $path, array $defaults = array(), array $requirements = array(), array $options = array(), ?string $host = '', $schemes = array(), $methods = array(), ?string $condition = '')`

`php -v` tells me PHP 7.2 is installed:

`PHP 7.2.2-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 1 2018 16:01:26) ( NTS )`

What's wrong here? Why does PHP 7.2 throw an error due to a syntax feature introduced in 7.1?

Vagrant version (`vagrant -v`) is 2.0.1.
Homestead version (`vagrant box list`) is 5.1.0.
Laravel version (`php artisan --version`) is 5.6.3.

Thanks

Comment: whats the php version inside the vagrant box you are using? Did you try to ssh into vagrant and check the php version there?

Comment: @NikolaGavric, I did. It's the output I've quoted, PHP 7.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I also had to update the Homestead package from Github:
`git pull origin master`

Docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#updating-homestead

For an explanation of Homestead box vs. Homestead package:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-upgrade/replies/381763